# How to display emojis in my app?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, image, sqlite, emoji

I have a Rails 4 app with a comment section. Right now, if I comment with an emoji from an iphone, it just displays as boxes on a computer. How can I get it to appear on a computer screen as a certain image, similar to what Facebook did?

So far, I have a fairly bare-bones comment system:

**view**

```
    <!-- form -->
    <%= form_for([@user, @comment], remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= #... %>
      <%= f.text_area :text %>
      <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    <% end %>
    <!-- comments -->
    <% @user.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= comment.text %><br>
    <% end %>
```

I'm using sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a font that doesn't support emojis. An emoji is just a letter like any other. You see an "A" between the quotation marks because the font here has the A character defined. You don't see a train emoji between these quotes: "", because this font doesn't have any emojis present. There should be plenty of web fonts you can use that have emoji support.

Comment: Is there one you've been using that you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look at https://github.com/github/gemoji it comes with a handy `emojify` helper.